# Setting mapped port of TestContainer in DynamicPropertySource

Tags: ibm-mq, testcontainers

Given: TestContainer as an integration framework, Spring boot app, ibm mq as a broker I try to test it, cant connect with default settings, catch:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 118 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost/127.0.0.1:1414' rejected. [1=java.net.ConnectException[Connection refused (Connection refused)],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414,4=TCP,5=Socket.connect]],3=localhost(1414),4=,5=RemoteTCPConnection.bindAndConnectSocket]
```

Container declaration:

````
@Container
static GenericContainer<?> mqContainer = new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("ibmcom/mq"))
        .withEnv("LICENSE", "accept")
        .withEnv("MQ_QMGR_NAME", "QM1")
        .withEnv("MQ_USER_NAME","admin")
        .withCommand("--volume q1data:/mnt/mqm")
        .withExposedPorts(1414);```
````

All the settings in yml file for queue look unrelated, cause there is no any port specific stuff:

```
ibm:
      mq:
        channel: DEV.APP.SVRCONN
        queue-manager: QM1
        user: admin
        password: passw0rd
        use-i-b-m-cipher-mappings: false
        user-authentication-m-q-c-s-p: false
        #ssl-cipher-spec: ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        ssl.enabled: false
```

I asked TC framework supporters and they advised to set host and port for spring in dynamic properties, which seems legit. The only problem I cant find correct settings to use. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tutorial here: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-jms-application-development-with-spring-boot/, these could be the following property:

```
ibm.mq.connName=localhost(1414)
```

So your `@DynamicPropertySource` could be something like:

```
@DynamicPropertySource
static void registerMqProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
  registry.add("ibm.mq.connName", 
               () -> String.format("%s(%d)", 
                                   mqContainer.getHost(), 
                                   mqContainer.getFirstMappedPort()));
}
```